# Exclude category from this loop

Tags: php, wordpress

i have this code that print all woocommerce categories and i want to hide a single cateogry from this loop.

```
<?php
$get_featured_cats = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'hide_empty'   => '0',
  'include'      => $cat_array,

);

$all_categories = get_categories( $get_featured_cats );
$j = 1;
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
  echo '<div class="col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp ">
        <div class="card mb-3" style="">
        <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">';
  $cat_id   = $cat->term_id;
  $cat_link = get_category_link( $cat_id );

  $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); // Get Category Thumbnail
  $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
  if ( $image ) {
    echo '<div class="col-md-4 mini-card-categorie-citta" style="background-image: url(' . $image . ')"></div>';
  }
  echo '<div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body">
        <a href="'. $cat_link .'"><h6 class="card-title" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">';
  echo $cat->name; // Get Category Name
  echo '</h6></a>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>';
  $j++;
}
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

There are any way to exclude from this list -> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxnn8.png) the category "Traslados" ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A basic condition seems sufficient to solve your problem. What have you tried? Show us your best attempt.

Comment: unset array key of "Traslados" in $all_categories before loop

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the ID of the category you want to exclude, after that, a simple conditional check before printing out the category. Like so:

```
    $imageCategoryId = 12 //Or whatever your image category id is
    foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->term_id !== $imageCategoryId) {
            //Display category
        }
    }
```